# Can I use someone else's credit card for flight booking?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, payment-cards, american-airlines, domestic-travel

Can I book a domestic flight in US using my father's credit card? The flight is operated by Mesa airlines.

Comment: This question is unfortunately far too broad. It depends entirely on the specific airline's conditions.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Are you aware of any airlines that don't let you use somebody else's card? Any such airline can wave goodbye to most business users.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Just to mention the first few I found with a simple Google search: Singapore Airlines, Delta, All Nippon, Eva Air, SriLankan Airlines, Philippines Airlines, Turkish Airlines, Jetstar and Thai Airways.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some airlines may have different rules for registered business, eg Emirates: "Business Rewards administrators may also pay for their organizations members bookings by credit card, if the country of departure offers credit card payment."

Comment: Yes, some non-US carriers seem to care about who bought the ticket, but the OP is asking about a **domestic US** ticket. I've regularly bought tickets for my parents to visit me--no problem.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Most of the airlines quoted have some ability to waive the requirement; for instance by faxing a signed indemnity back to their office. And if you book through a travel agent, then the restriction doesn't apply; the TA bears the risk of fraud. The reason airlines treat cards with suspicion is that credit card fraud costs the global airline industry about 1 billion USD per year. (Source: https://www.europol.europa.eu/content/118-arrested-global-action-against-online-fraudsters-airline-sector)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which Airline you use, like Qatar Airways ask you in advance to get an official permission from the card owner in case he is not flying with you, other airlines mostly in EU countries doesn't ask. so let us know which airline you are willing to use.